# Can I still use a GPT secondary hard drive if I converted it to MBR

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, mbr, gpt

I'm owner of an MSI GT60 laptop with preinstalled Windows 8.
The W8 OS is installed on an 128GB SSD (C:) GPT format.
There is a secondary 600GB DATA hard drive (D:) GPT format.

My goal is to install a dual boot Windows 7 in a 100 GB partition of the D: (let's name it Z:).

I reached the point "You can't install Windows 7 on a GPT formated partition".

After research, I found out the following process:

- delete all partitions from D:
- convert D: in MBR format
- make new partitions (in my case : 500GB D:, and 100GB Z:)
- install W7 on Z:

Here are my two questions :
When I'll run with Windows 8, will I still be able to access D: files, install programs on D: and run them in Windows 8 environment ?

If yes, will it affect the efficience of these programs ?

Note: I dont care about data loss on D:. I saved it.

Edit:
I did the conversion and everything is OK as said below.

For user willing to make a W7 dual boot as me:
After the conversion of the D: HD from GPT to MBR, I had to remove my C: SSD because of an 0x80300024 error while selecting the Z: partition for installing W7. Then, I connected it back and everything was OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if done properly you will be able to access files, install programs and run them in a Windows 8 environment.  You would have to install them from Windows 8 and point it to the drive you wish to store it on.

Edit: I do not believe it will impact efficiency noticeably.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I will try this in the following days and bring feed back.

Comment: I did the conversion and as you said, I can still access the D: and Z: drivers from my Win 8 environment. I didn't check the efficiency yet but it seems about the same. Thanks for the answer. I will edit my post to add further information about my Dual Boot goal.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine efficiency would be affected noticeably.  If it does it will be my a miniscule amount only measurable by metrics, not experience.  Please edit your post when you have the information, it could be helpful to have here. I'm glad I was able to assist you with your question.